# join query in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am having table structure like this

```
   table1       table2

    pid  pname       pid uid  cat
    1       a          1   1   1
    2       b          1   2   1
    3       c          1   3   1

select * from table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.pid=t2.pid where t2.uid=1 AND t2.cat=1
```

it's select the two rows

i don't want to group pid because i may have same pid in table one so i need to get only number of rows matched with pid

This may be silly question but i tried hard i couldn't get anything .

I hope you  people can help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want your result to look like?

Comment: "it's select the two rows" That query with the data you posted will only return 1 row.

Comment: @Sugerman, "you people" = "Programmers"?? **X-)**

Comment: i put real query and table in following url for ref

Comment: http://optisolbusiness.com/gonzobidz/testpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the count of rows that match:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t2.uid=1
```

Your LEFT join is unnecessary, since you are filtering by table2.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: @gowi Just add ` AND t2.cat=1` to the end of the query.

Comment: i put real query and table in following url for ref  http://optisolbusiness.com/gonzobidz/testpage

Comment: @gowri Does the query i posted not work? could you please explain in your question what you want the results to look like?

Comment: i wanna select only the fourth row from table 1 .. please check http://optisolbusiness.com/gonzobidz/testpage

Comment: @gowri So add `AND t2.product_id = 19` Which table is `table1` and which is `table2`?